# Unwanted SVGAnimatedString created along with SVG elements

Tags: javascript, android, html, svg, webview

My app uses a WebView to inject some HTML elements in the displayed HTML document. It can inject a SVG element (absolute position) with a polygon as a child. It sets the class attribute of the above mentioned elements to a special value so they are filtered when performing certain Javascript operations.

```
svg=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
svg.setAttribute('class',SPECIAL_CLASS);
...
child=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon');
child.setAttribute('class',SPECIAL_CLASS);
...
svg.appendChild(child);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Unfortunately I see that SVGAnimatedString unwanted elements are created. I am not sure what they are but they are definitely created along with injected SVG elements. I could filter them but I cannot be sure the web document has not legitimate SVGAnimatedString or other similar elements that have to be processed.

How to avoid those unwanted elements being created? What they are? Could I find other similar elements according to where the SVG elements are placed over the other HTML elements?

Comment: Do you get elements named SVGAnimatedString? If so, please add more code or a full example showing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "unwanted" SVGAnimatedString elements were just the SVG elements the app created, just their className yields the string SVGAnimatedString as value. className for SVG seems to be read-only so I used another attribute to flag those elements:

```
svgElement.setAttributeNS('http://www.myNS.com/myNS',ATTRIBUTE_NAME,value);
```

and

```
svgElement.getAttributeNS('http://www.myNS.com/myNS',ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

In SVG class attributes on styleable elements (svg and polygon are styleable) are modelled by the [SVGAnimatedString](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGStylable) type.

```
interface SVGStylable {

  readonly attribute SVGAnimatedString className;
  readonly attribute CSSStyleDeclaration style;

  CSSValue getPresentationAttribute(in DOMString name);
};
```

Comment: So what I have to do to set the class so they are filtered?

Comment: Avoid setting class attributes I suppose.

Comment: An alternative is to start using the newer [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) method since that works the same on both html and svg elements.

Comment: @Erik Dahlström Aren't the SVGAnimatedString created if I use classList instead of className?

Comment: @P5music not sure why that's a concern TBH, "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?", or in this case: "if you use an API that doesn't expose some other API, does the other API exist?"

Comment: However, I cannot check it out because my app is targeted to low sdk API level (to keep WebView in quirks mode) so this new function is not available